# Octonion Grassmanian?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, octonions

[I just learnt that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1922/what-is-the-cayley-projective-plane) the octonion projective space $\mathbf{OP}^n$ exists only for $n=1,2$. How about the "octonion Grassmannian", i.e. the space of $k$-subspace of $\mathbf O^n$? For which values of $(k,n)$ does it make sense?